# Python Calling a raise exception instead of returning in recursive function

Tags: python, exception, recursion

I have to check how much faster works a code where I throw exception to end a recursion instead of return

My code with return looks this way:

```
    def factorial(self, n):
    if n==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n* self.factorial(n-1)
```

Now my code with raise:

```
def factorial2(self, n):
    if n==0:
        raise Exc(1)
    else:
        return n* self.factorial2(n-1)
```

I don't know, if it should look this way and what should I do to get a value
I've tried sth like this

```
try:
    print factorial2(n)
except Exc:
    1
```

But it doesn't work. I don't even know if I'm close to good solution.

Can anybody help me, give me some tips?

Comment: If you want to measure performance, throwing an exception is not a good idea.

Comment: why not @the fourth eye?

Comment: I think thats what she's trying to measure ... the performance difference between the two ... (its just an alternative way of exiting the recursion ...)  tbh the speed difference between them will probably be pretty minimal

Comment: Raising an exception (unless you catch it in every instance of `factorial2`) defeats the purpose of a recursive call. It might be faster, but it will also be wrong, because the correctness of the function depends on the multiplication which occurs *after* `factorial2` returns successfully.

Comment: @JoranBeasley When an exception is raised, shouldnt the stack be unwound?

Comment: @thefourtheye If the current callee does not catch the exception, the caller is given a chance. The exception propagates up the call stack until it is caught, or the interpreter itself receives the exception and exits with a stack trace.

Comment: I think you will hit the recursion limits long before this sort of optimization makes any kind of noticeable difference

Answer (score 2):

you need the try/except in the else part of this function  ... since all calls will eventually raise this exception if you listen outside then all your work is lost

```
def factorial2(self, n):
    if n==0:
        raise Exc(1)
    else:
        try:
           return n* self.factorial2(n-1)
        except Exc:
           return n
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know why I even haven't thinking about giving it together.