# How do I exit a recursive DFS algorithm after a certain time in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, timeout, exit

I have a recursive depth first search function in python that I want to exit completely from (the entire stack) after a certain time. The recursive function is aware of the time remaining (it's passed a variable called time_remaining), and when this time_remaining is less than say 100 ms, I want to exit out of the entire recursion stack, and return some default values. What's the best way to accomplish this in python?

Comment: Share your function.

Comment: Conditionally return when the time runs out?

Comment: Have you tried this yourself?  Can you share what you tried?

Comment: @wwii - Won't work if the algorithm is n layers deep - it'll have to keep going up the stack.

Comment: @StephenRauch Not sure what I can share, since I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: ```...exit out of the entire recursion stack...``` - You want to go sideways not *up*?

Comment: Why do you want to "exit out of the entire recursion stack"?

Comment: @wwii I want to simply terminate and return a value.

Comment: @sigjuice Say my stack is a million nodes deep, and I have 10 ms remaining and that's not enough to go up the stack. I simply want to quit and return a value and not want to go up the stack closing each function.

Comment: @max_max_mir how do you know if 10 ms is not enough to go up the stack?  Have you measured this in some way?

Comment: The 10 ms was an example. If I could go back up the stack in the allocated time, then this question would be moot. The point is to maximize the time I have left - for example, in a search tree where I want to go as deep as I can before I have to bounce out.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do this.  It uses an exception to unwind the stack, and a decorator to check the time remaining at each call to the recursion.

```
import time

class TimeRemainingExpired(Exception):
    pass

def enforce_time_remaining(f):
    """ decorator to check time remaining and raise if expired """
    def new_f(*args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('_time_remaining_end_time') is None:
            kwargs['_time_remaining_end_time'] = \
                time.time() + kwargs['time_remaining']
            print(kwargs['_time_remaining_end_time'])
            print(kwargs['time_remaining'])
        if time.time() >= kwargs['_time_remaining_end_time']:
            raise TimeRemainingExpired
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return new_f


@enforce_time_remaining
def recurse(**kwargs):
    time.sleep(.01)
    recurse(**kwargs)

print(time.time())
try:
    recurse(time_remaining=1)
except TimeRemainingExpired:
    print('Time Expired')
print(time.time())
```

Comment: Does this behave differently than just returning if the time is up?

Comment: It throws an exception on time expiring.

Comment: @StephenRauch This is definitely a clean way to implement, but is there a way to go straight to the top of the calling function stack instead of going up each level?

Comment: This does not go up each level.  Since it throws an exception it will go all the way up until the exception is caught.  In the example, the `TimeRemainingExpired` is caught in the last three lines.  In fact, in the example, the recursing function sleeps for `0.01` seconds, and the entire process is given one second, so it will descend 100 levels, and then unwind the entire stack with  the exception.

Comment: Seems like the exception would be passed to each previous caller all the way *up* the recursion stack till it is caught *at the top* - similar to just returning  See the sixth comment to http://stackoverflow.com/q/19367610/2823755

Comment: I am unaware of any way for python to throw away the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you need to start a thread to stop a global time variable after a set allocated amount of time, then allow your search function to run afterwards and check when that max time condition is false or in some state that tells you the program is no longer suppose to recursively continue.

This is an example of a recursive function, I've passed in an iteration so you can see it go and artificially slowed it down. You need to start a thread to start a global timer, then check that global timer each time you call the recursive function.

```
import time
from threading import Thread

# create a global variable time that is ture
global_time = True 

# start the timer
def start_timer():
        time.sleep(0.1) # 1/10 second
        # Make sure you're referencing the GLOBAL time variable.
        global global_time
        # After 1/10 second, the timer will stop.
        global_time = False
        print("time stopped")

# The itteration variable is just for display.
def dfs(itteration):
        # Put your search logic here.

        # Again, make sure you're referencing the GLOBAL time variable.
        global global_time
        if global_time == True:
                # Artificially slowing down the search function.
                time.sleep(0.01)
                # Just print the iteration so you can see what's going on.
                itteration = itteration + 1 
                print(itteration)
                return dfs(itteration)
        else:
                return "DONE"

# First start the timer.
timer_thread = Thread(target = start_timer)
timer_thread.start()
# Run the search function.
print(dfs(0))
```

Since the timer is 1/10 second until it's false and each itteration will take 1/100, it should only run 10 times. This is my result:

```
python time.py 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
time stopped
DONE
```

It's important that you use `global` or sle the dfs function will not know that `global_time` is the one you set on line 4 and it will go on forever.

Note my python version is 3.5 and threading may be different in the 2.7 version.

Unrelated note: DFS is terribly inefficient. You should be using BFS ([Breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)) or [A* search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) (which is proven to be [optimal](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/30778/why-is-the-a-search-heuristic-optimal-even-if-it-underestimates-costs)), although this is not related to the question.

Comment: Thanks @display-name, but this still has to unwind through all the stack. Instead of return dfs(iteration), if you just call dfs(iteration), assign it to a variable, and print that after the dfs call, won't it first print DONE and then the numbers 9 through 1 backwords? I need the entire stack to just stop (or even throw an error). Maybe what I am asking for is not possible?

Comment: If you don't start the timer thread, nothing will set it to false which will mean the `dfs` will run forever. Maybe I'm not understanding your question? Note that you can get rid of `itteration`. It's just for display.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "still has to unwind through all the stack". There's no unwinding here. It's just checking a global variable and happens to have done 9 iterations before it was done, right after `time stopped` was printed.

Comment: What I mean by unwinding through the stack is that when your child recursion returns DONE, it then passes control to the parent function that called it. It then passes control back to its parent and so on. This is okay if I have a few nodes. But say I am at a billion layers deep in a search tree and I am running out of time (think chess) - I need to quit, return a value and pass control back to the topmost function in the stack.